# How to make Wordpress use authentication from Parent Site

Tags: authentication

I have a site already, I am adding wordpress to it. THe current site already has user authentication. I want to continue using that authentication and I want my user to be able to seamlessly move to the blog, be recognized as a logged in user and be able to comment and or contribute to the blog. I'm hoping someone call tell me how or point me in the direction I should be going.

For more information on the current systemm I am using HybridAuth which allows my users to sign in with Facebook or Google (among others) it also easily lets me get the users friend or contact lists.

Any help is much appreciated!